# Syntax Error ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting a syntax error that I don't seem to find an answer to and I was hoping that someone would be able to see what I am missing.

I am trying to add data in a database by using the following code but it throws a Syntax error message and I don't really see why.

This is my code:

```
 // Get data from textboxes.
    string last = txtLastName.Text;
    string first = txtFirstName.Text;
    string gender = txtGender.Text;
    string email = txtEmail.Text;
       int age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
    string pref = "";    
    // Compose SQL command string.
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES"  + 
        "('" + first + "', '" + last +
        "', '" + gender + "', '" + age + "', " + email + ");";
```

And this is the Error message

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'email.example@email.com'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'email.example@email.com'.

Source Error: 


Line 50:     // Create command object and execute insert statement.
Line 51:     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, c);
Line 52:     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 53:         
Line 54:     // Close connection.

Source File: d:\DePaul\Winter 2012\IT 330\Projects\Proj5-Nicolaides\Proj5-Nicolaides\application-form.aspx    Line: 52 

Stack Trace: 


[OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'email.example@email.com'.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +992124
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +255
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +188
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +161
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +113
   ASP.application_form_aspx.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\DePaul\Winter 2012\IT 330\Projects\Proj5-Nicolaides\Proj5-Nicolaides\application-form.aspx:52
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you need to enclose your last value in single quotes:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES"  + 
    "('" + first + "', '" + last +
    "', '" + gender + "', '" + age + "', '" + email + "');";
```

Your **LARGER** problem is that you are vulnerable to SQL Injection by not using parameterized queries.  This would be prudent:

```
string sql = @"insert into application
    values(@first, @last, @gender, @age, @email)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", first);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", last);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
```

Comment: As I said already, this is a test application and it will not go live. Thanks for your help and concern

Answer (score 2):

**You are missing an apostrophe after your email variable is inserted.**

This code should work

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES"  + 
    "('" + first + "', '" + last +
    "', '" + gender + "', '" + age + "', " + email + "');";
```

**WARNING**

- Your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack
- Consider using Parameterized SQL. This will prevent SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

**How to run a SQL Server Query in VB.NET**

This should translate easily to your C#

1. **Create SQL Command** - You aren't setting the connection property of the SQLCommand. You can do this without adding a line of code. *This is the cause of your error.*

   ```
   myCommand = New SqlCommand("Insert Into MyTable values (@value1, @value2)", MyConnection)
   ```

   - Note: @value1, @value2 -- these come into play later. These are placeholders for SQL Parameters. These will save your butt.
2. **Insert Parameter Values** - You need to utilize SQL Parameters, despite the fact that you are not using a Stored Procedure.

   ```
   CMD.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TXT_BookdID.Text)
   CMD.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.varchar, 500).Value = TXT_BookName.Text
   ```
3. **Create a function to execute your SQL Commands**

   ```
   ''' <summary>Executes a SqlCommand on the Main DB Connection. Usage: Dim ds As DataSet = ExecuteCMD(CMD) </summary>'
   ''' <param name="CMD">The command type will be determined based upon whether or not the commandText has a space in it. If it has a space, it is a Text command ("select ... from .."), '
   ''' otherwise if there's just one token, it's a stored procedure command</param>'
   Function ExecuteCMD(ByRef CMD As SqlCommand) As DataSet
       Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("main").ConnectionString
       Dim ds As New DataSet()

       Try
           Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
           CMD.Connection = connection

           'Assume that it's a stored procedure command type if there is no space in the command text. Example: "sp_Select_Customer" vs. "select * from Customers"
           If CMD.CommandText.Contains(" ") Then
               CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
           Else
               CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
           End If

           Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
           adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300

           'fill the dataset'
           adapter.Fill(ds)
           connection.Close()

       Catch ex As Exception
           ' The connection failed. Display an error message.'
           Throw New Exception("Database Error: " & ex.Message)
       End Try

       Return ds
   End Function
   ```

Comment: I needed two single quotes. I am not using parameters because its just a test for a future project so it won't really go live. Thanks for the help and the suggestions though :)

Comment: @Crematorio "Won't really go live" is in the category of "famous last words", I'm afraid.

Comment: @Crematorio It is not a burden to use parameterized SQL. Look through my code, you'll be doing yourself a favor.

Comment: @hamlin11 I use  parameterized SQL when I am dealing with actual databases and live websites. This is just a personal project.

Comment: @Christian.K I didn't understand what you mean. This application will not go live. :)

Comment: @Crematorio See [this](http://www.netqtic.com/views/DeveloperQuotes.htm) site for some examples.

Comment: @Christian.K That's so funny...I hear some of them at the office some times!!!! Good thing I meant what I was saying!!! If I upload such a code I would probably get fired the next minute :)

Answer (score 0):

It Should be (i think you email field would be of string ype so single quotes are required)

```
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES"  + 
    "('" + first + "', '" + last +
    "', '" + gender + "', '" + age + "', '" + email + "');";
```

Comment: While technically "correct", without the slightest word of warning about the apparent SQL injection, this _almost_ deserves a down vote.

Comment: @Christian.K i was just suggested where the error is

Comment: Yes I thought so, that is why I said _almost_ deserves a down vote.